# app crashes on button click when editText is empty

Tags: android

i am creating a single screen app of grocery but while checking total price if a user doesnt type anything it should by default be equal to 0 but instead my app crashes 
Below is the code for same

Activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ashis.singlescreenapp.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/headline"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/grocery_logo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/qty_heading"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView_qty"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView_qty"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText_apples"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Apples ($2 per piece)" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText_orange"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Orange($3 per piece)" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText_mango"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Mango($4 per piece)" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText_banana"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Banana($1 per piece)" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
        android:text="@string/btn_confirm"
        android:onClick="onbuttonClicked"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/textView_result"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_confirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="checkPrice" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ashis.singlescreenapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_apples,editText_orange,editText_mango,editText_banana;
    int apples,orange,mango,banana;
    TextView textView_result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    }

    public void checkPrice(View view)
    {
        editText_apples=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_apples);
        editText_orange=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_orange);
        editText_banana=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_banana);
        editText_mango=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mango);
        textView_result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);
        apples=Integer.parseInt(editText_apples.getText().toString());
        orange=Integer.parseInt(editText_orange.getText().toString());
        mango=Integer.parseInt(editText_mango.getText().toString());
        banana=Integer.parseInt(editText_banana.getText().toString());
        if (editText_apples.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            apples=0;
        }
        else if (editText_banana.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            banana=0;
        }
        else if (editText_orange.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            orange=0;
        }
        else if (editText_mango.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            mango=0;
        }
        else {
            int result = getPrice(apples, orange, mango, banana);
            textView_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        }
    }
    private int getPrice(int apples, int orange, int mango, int banana) {

        int result= (apples*2) + (orange*3) + (mango*4) + (banana);

    return result;
    }
/*
    public void onbuttonClicked(View view)
    {

        String email_body = "Dear Grocery Store, \n" + "Send all the following  ";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"ashish.choudhary@groceryStore.com");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT," Send All these Product");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"");

    }
*/
}
```

Here is the logCat when i click on Confirm Button

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.ashis.singlescreenapp, PID: 22748
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21350)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21350) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                       at com.example.ashis.singlescreenapp.MainActivity.checkPrice(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21350) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Here's your error `Invalid int: ""` at line 36 in MainActivity. Check that piece of code.

Comment: editText_apples.getText().toString() is empty you r trying to parse that as integer so its failing. Modify your if else condition check

Comment: you are getting null here..  **Invalid int: ""**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to format an empty String. Just check

```
if(!edittext.getText().toString().equals("")) {
   apples = Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString()); 
} else {
    apples = 0;
}
```

Or you could use the short form:

```
apples = edittext.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `parseInt` before you check for empty string. `parseInt` on empty string will throw exception. You should in any case surround `parseInt` with a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText_apples=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_apples);
        editText_orange=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_orange);
        editText_banana=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_banana);
        editText_mango=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mango);
        textView_result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);
        checkPrice();

    }

    public void checkPrice()
    {
        apples = edittext_apples.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
        orange=editText_orange..getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
        mango=editText_mango..getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
        banana=editText_banana.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
        ...............
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your code and you see - you are trying to parse int before checking text.
You need something like this for each edit text:

```
if (editText_apples.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    apples=0;
} else {
    apples=Integer.parseInt(editText_apples.getText().toString());
}
```

or short variant:

```
apples = editText_apples.getText().toString().isEmpty() ? 0 
: Integer.parseInt(editText_apples.getText().toString());
```

To be sure, that in edit text will be only numbers, you can add inputType for edit text:

```
<EditText
...
android:inputType="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues trying to parse for integers from empty strings. Try replace this piece of code:

```
apples=Integer.parseInt(editText_apples.getText().toString());
        orange=Integer.parseInt(editText_orange.getText().toString());
        mango=Integer.parseInt(editText_mango.getText().toString());
        banana=Integer.parseInt(editText_banana.getText().toString());
        if (editText_apples.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            apples=0;
        }
        else if (editText_banana.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            banana=0;
        }
        else if (editText_orange.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            orange=0;
        }
        else if (editText_mango.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            mango=0;
        }
        else {
            int result = getPrice(apples, orange, mango, banana);
            textView_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        }
```

with this:

```
String txt1 = editText_apples.getText().toString();
apples=Integer.parseInt("".equals(txt1.trim()) ? "0" : txt1);

String txt2 = editText_orange.getText().toString();
orange=Integer.parseInt("".equals(txt2.trim()) ? "0" : txt2);

String txt3 = editText_mango.getText().toString();
mango=Integer.parseInt("".equals(txt3.trim()) ? "0" : txt3);

String txt4 = editText_banana.getText().toString();
banana=Integer.parseInt("".equals(txt4.trim()) ? "0" : txt4);

 int result = getPrice(apples, orange, mango, banana);
         textView_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise view while setting content

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                EditText editText_apples,editText_orange,editText_mango,editText_banana;
                int apples,orange,mango,banana;
                TextView textView_result;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    editText_apples=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_apples);
                    editText_orange=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_orange);
                    editText_banana=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_banana);
                    editText_mango=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mango);
                    textView_result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);


                }

                public void checkPrice(View view)
                {

                  if(TextUtils.isDigitOnly(editText_apples.getText().toString()){ 
                      apples=Integer.parseInt(editText_apples.getText().toString());
                   }else{
                        apples=0;
                   }
                   if(TextUtils.isDigitOnly(editText_orange.getText().toString()){ 
                      orange=Integer.parseInt(editText_orange.getText().toString());
                   }else{
                         orange=0;
                   }
                   if(TextUtils.isDigitOnly(editText_mango.getText().toString()){

                      mango=Integer.parseInt(editText_mango.getText().toString());
                   }else{
                         mango=0;
                   }
                    if(TextUtils.isDigitOnly(editText_banana.getText().toString()){
                       banana=Integer.parseInt(editText_banana.getText().toString());
                    }else{
                          banana=0;
                    }

                    int result = getPrice(apples, orange, mango, banana);
                    textView_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));

                }
                private int getPrice(int apples, int orange, int mango, int banana) {

                    int result= (apples*2) + (orange*3) + (mango*4) + (banana);

                return result;
                }
            }
```

in your code at the time of button clicks views are getting initialized and then u will be able to use them and the values are null in edit text so casting them in integer generates null pointer exception.